# Nonlinear least squares optimized Jacobian calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-solver, least-squares

I have a nonlinear least squares problem, in which I am trying to minimize residuals which can be divided into four classes:
$$
\min_x ||\epsilon(x)||^2 + ||\xi(x)||^2 + ||\delta(x)||^2 + ||s(x)||^2
$$
The parameter vector $x$ can be naturally divided into four classes of parameters, $x = \left( x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \right)$. Some of the residuals are linear in the parameters, and others are not. The full Jacobian matrix is:
$$
J = \pmatrix{
\mathcal{E}_1 & \mathcal{E}_2 & 0 & \mathcal{E}_4(x) \\
\Xi_1 & \Xi_2 & \Xi_3 & 0 \\
\Delta_1 & \Delta_2 & 0 & 0 \\
S_1(x) & S_2(x) & S_3(x) & 0
}
$$
So you can see some blocks in the Jacobian don't depend on the parameters $x$ (these correspond to the residuals which are linear in $x$). So for example, $\mathcal{E}_i = \partial \epsilon / \partial x_i$.

Now since its a nonlinear least squares problem, I need to iterate, and solve the following linear least squares problem at each iteration:
$$
\min_p
\left| \left|
\pmatrix{ \epsilon(x) \\ \xi(x) \\ \delta(x) \\ s(x) } - J p
\right| \right|^2
$$
and then set $x := x + p$.

I want to take advantage of the sparse structure of $J$, and also the parts of $J$ which don't depend on $x$ to make the calculation as fast as possible. Another issue, is that $J$ is too large to fit in memory at once, so I am using the normal equations approach. $J$ has roughly 10 million rows and 20,000 columns.

With the normal equations approach, I can separate $J^T J$ into a part which can be precomputed prior to the iteration, and a part which needs to be computed on each iteration:
$$
J^T J =
\pmatrix{
\mathcal{E}_1^T \mathcal{E}_1 + \Xi_1^T \Xi_1 + \Delta_1^T \Delta_1 &&& \\
\mathcal{E}_2^T \mathcal{E}_1 + \Xi_2^T \Xi_1 + \Delta_2^T \Delta_1 & \mathcal{E}_2^T \mathcal{E}_2 + \Xi_2^T \Xi_2 + \Delta_2^T \Delta_2 && \\
\Xi_3^T \Xi_1 & \Xi_3^T \Xi_2 & \Xi_3^T \Xi_3 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
}
+ \pmatrix{
S_1(x)^T S_1(x) &&& \\
S_2(x)^T S_1(x) & S_2(x)^T S_2(x) && \\
S_3(x)^T S_1(x) & S_3(x)^T S_2(x) & S_3(x)^T S_3(x) & \\
\mathcal{E}_4(x)^T \mathcal{E}_1 & \mathcal{E}_4(x)^T \mathcal{E}_2 & 0 & \mathcal{E}_4(x)^T \mathcal{E}_4(x)
}
$$
So the first term doesn't depend on $x$, is small enough to fit in memory, and can be precomputed. The second term does depend on $x$ and must be computed on each iteration. I wrote only the lower triangles since these matrices are symmetric. Once I have the full $J^T J$, I use a Cholesky decomposition to compute the step $p$.

My question is: **is the above approach the best way to implement something like this?**

In the future, I would like to add more parameters to my model (i.e. $x_5, x_6, \dots$) which would increase the number of columns in my Jacobian. But then the $J^T J$ matrix will get more and more complicated, and it is already becoming difficult to compute all the different terms in the matrix (without making mistakes!). **Does anyone have any suggestions for a strategy to compute all of these terms efficiently and simply? Is there a better method I should be using, such as TSQR?**

Comment: With 10 million observations, your problem is amazingly over constrained.  You would probably get perfectly good results with a random sampling from those 10 million observations- this could speed up your computations significantly.

Comment: Automatic Differentiation (AD) tools could prove helpful in this situation.  However, these tend to be very language specific.  What language are you implementing this in?

Comment: I'm using C and I've never used AD tools